# Why does ganz have no declension in this sentence?

Tags: declension, adjective-ending

I'm sorry I can't formulate my question in German yet. I'm still doing my best to learn. So I'll ask in English anyway because I really need an answer.

I was reading this story (https://www.thegermanproject.com/stories/chicken-little) and this particular sentence got me thinking why ganz have no declension.

> Er ist weder groß noch klein. Er ist weder dick noch dünn. Er ist weder schlau noch dumm. Henry Hühnchen ist ein ganz normales Huhn.

I know that adjectives with sein become predicative complements and the adjectives receive no declension. But why does normales have -es?

and right after that something again appeared.

> An einem ganz normalen Morgen isst Henry Hühnchen in der Küche sein Frühstück. Er mag Toast mit Butter und Kaffee mit Sahne.

ganz is also without any declension and normales have (-es) but now there is no sein. So NOW I have no excuse (and no idea) either.

I looked into double adjectives. But it seems they all have to receive a declension. So what's going on here?

A little help here? Am I missing something? Is there a grammatical rule I am not aware of?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ganz

Comment: wow, is it an adverb? No wonder it has no declension. that's the answer, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributive adjectives, i.e. those modifying a noun, are inflected.

> Er hat ein **ganzes** Buch zu dem Thema geschrieben.
> *He wrote a whole book on the subject.*

Adverbial adjectives, i.e. those modifying verbs or, as in this case, other adjectives, are not inflected.

> Gestern ist ein **ganz neues** Buch zu dem Thema erschienen.
> *A completely new book on the subject was published yesterday.*

When *ganz* is used adverbially, it can also express a restriction, a moderate degree.

> Es war ein **ganz angenehmer** Tag.
> *It was a pretty (fairly, quite) nice day.*

In your examples, *ganz* modifies *normal*, expressing that something is wholly normal. But *ganz* could also modify the noun and would then be inflected.

> Er isst ein **ganzes** Huhn.
> *He eats a whole chicken.*
>
> Er lag den **ganzen** Morgen im Bett.
> *He lay in bed all morning*.

Comment: I voted this one because it is more complete. Source confirming his answer: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/German/Grammar/Adjectives_and_Adverbs#Adjectives

Answer (score 2):

Just look at how "ein ganz normaler Morgen" would be translated into English.

It is not *a total normal morning* but *a totally normal morning*.

*Ganz* here translates to *totally*, getting a -ly suffix because it is not an adjective but an adverb. Adverbs are uninflected in German.

Comment: *Ganz* is an adverb in this case, but it can also be an adjective: An einem *ganz* normalen Tag isst er ein *ganzes* Hühnchen.

Comment: I've edited the answer to make this more clear.